# Silverlight TabItem content not scrolling

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, scroll

I have this XAML where I have tried to get TabItem content to scroll (without success).

```
<ex:TabControl>
  <ex:TabItem Header="General">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource tabMenuItem}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
  </ex:TabItem>
  <ex:TabItem Header="Prices (Item)">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding NonModifierPricesView}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource tabMenuItemPrices}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
  </ex:TabItem>
</ex:TabControl>
```

When my TabControl gets resized so that the TabItem is too small to display all the content, no scrollbars are displayed.  Have I done something wrong somewhere?

Edit : Requested XAML for tabMenuItemPrices

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="tabMenuItemPrices">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Prices (in order of priority)" />
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" x:Name="lstMenuItemPrices" SelectionMode="Single"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding }" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemPriceDataTemplate}" Height="140" >

                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateSelectedTaxGroupsCommand, ElementName=Editor}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </ListBox>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" >
                        <Button  Content="Move Up" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource MinimumIntegerToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=0, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <Button  Content="Move Down" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource MinimumIntegerToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=0, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" Content="New Price" Command="{Binding DataContext.AddPriceCommand, ElementName=Editor}" />
                        <Button Content="Remove Price" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemovePriceCommand, ElementName=Editor}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource MinimumIntegerToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=0, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Selected Price" Grid.Row="2" />

                <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <CheckBox Content="Amount Includes Tax" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.DTO.AmountIncludesTax, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Amount" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Cost" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height, GridBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Points" Grid.Row="3"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Interface ID" Grid.Row="4"/>

                    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}"
                                     Text="{Binding SelectedItem.DTO.Amount, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices, Converter={StaticResource DecimalToMoneyStringConverter}}" />
                    <CheckBox Content="Open" Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.DTO.IsOpenAmount, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}"/>

                    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.DTO.Cost, Converter={StaticResource DecimalToMoneyStringConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                     Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    <CheckBox Content="Inherit" Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.DTO.CostOverride, Converter={StaticResource CostToBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}" />

                    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.DTO.PointsEarned, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToStringConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                     Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"
                                     IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem.DTO.PointsEarnedInherited, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBooleanConverter}, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}"/>
                    <CheckBox Content="Inherit" Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.DTO.InheritPointsEarned, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}" />

                    <TextBox Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"
                                     Text="{Binding SelectedItem.DTO.InterfaceID, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}" />

                    <CheckBox Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Inherit tax from class" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.DTO.InheritTaxes, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

                    <ListBox Margin="{StaticResource DefaultMargin}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Repository.TaxGroups, ElementName=Editor}"
                                     IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem.DTO.InheritTaxes, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToEnabledConverter}, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices, ConverterParameter=false}">
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2, 2, 2, 0" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                            <Border Background="Transparent">
                                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                        Content="{Binding DTO.Name}" Padding="5,0,10,0" >
                                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectedItem.AddTaxGroupCommand, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}" CommandParameter="{Binding DTO.ID}" />
                                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectedItem.RemoveTaxGroupCommand, ElementName=lstMenuItemPrices}" CommandParameter="{Binding DTO.ID}" />
                                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                </CheckBox>
                                            </Border>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ScrollViewer's child needs to manage it's own height and width. Your outer most grid in your ContentTemplate does not specify a HorizontalAlignment or VerticalAlignment so it's defaulting to a value of stretch... you can try setting the alignments to left and top as follows:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

The bottom line is, the outer most container inside your control template must set it's height and width to it's contents, not the parent container.

Comment: posted.  It looks like the scrollviewer overflows the bottom of the TabItem, because I don't see the Down Arrow.

Comment: It didn't work.  Resizing the TabControl is still just pushing the scrollviewer out the bottom.  To me it looks like the TabItem control isn't telling its chilren what size they need to be.

Comment: strange... I can't recreate your issue. What does the TabControl parent XAML look like?

Comment: It was the only child of a stackpanel... just switched that to a grid and all is well now.  I didn't realize stack panels allow overflow.